# Intersection beetween two planes

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble finding the intersection line between these two planes:

$x+y-z=3$ and $2x+3z=7$.

I have tried to set up an equation like this:

$x+y=3+z$

$2x=7-3z$

then z = t which makes it

$x+y=3+t$

$2x=7-3t$

and then:

$x=3+t-y$
putting it into the 2nd equation gives:

$2(3+t-y)=7-3t$ and so on until I get to this point and then I get stuck:

$5t-1=2y$

There must be something I am doing wrong, maybe somone could give me a hand?

Comment: Why do you think so? Here, $t$ is your parameter so you want to solve the resulting 2x2 system by treating $t$ as a known value. Since you found $y$ use the first equation to solve for $x$ and you'll get the (parametric) equation for the intersection line.

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange your last equation to get $$y=-\frac12 + \frac52t.$$ Now place this last result into $x=3+t-y$, obtaining: $$x=3+t-\left(-\frac12 + \frac52t\right),$$     $$x= \frac72 - \frac32t.$$
Now you generate the intersection line by letting $t$ run over all real numbers. For example $t=0 \mapsto (\frac72,-\frac12,0)$ and $t=1 \mapsto (2,2,1)$.

Comment: Is this clear, @Zhi Hao ?